# How does Sombra's "Power Outage" achievement works?

Tags: achievements, overwatch

One of the two Sombra's achievements is "Power Outage", which description is the following:

> Hack 6 enemies at once as Sombra in Quick or Competitive Play.

I heard many people say that you could only unlock this achievement when hacking the whole enemy team with [EMP](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Sombra#EMP). The achievement doesn't mention this skill though, and only mentions that you need to hack 6 enemies. My idea is that it could be possible to hack one enemy with Sombra's [Hack](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Sombra#Hack) ability, and then to reach the 5 other members of the enemy team and to use EMP to hack the rest of them, making all the 6 players technically hacked.

Would it be possible to get the achievement this way, or is the achievement misleading and it is only possible to get it by hacking the 6 members of the enemy team with EMP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only requirement for the achievement is that all 6 players of the enemy team are hacked by you at the same time. Whether the hack is from EMP or the regular Hack ability doesn't matter.

It is, however, much easier to catch all 6 enemies in the same EMP than to try to run into 5 enemies after revealing yourself.